# Update table column based on multi row comparison operation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max

I have following table in postgres

```
id          num
EBI-1002144 1
EBI-1002144 1
EBI-1002142 2
EBI-1002142 2
EBI-1002635 1
EBI-1002635 1
EBI-1002635 2
EBI-1002635 2
EBI-1003351 1
EBI-1003351 1
EBI-1003351 2
EBI-1003351 2
EBI-1003469 1
EBI-1003469 1
EBI-1003469 2
EBI-1003469 2
EBI-1003574 1
EBI-1003574 1
EBI-1003574 2
EBI-1003574 2
```

I want to append another column to this table based on following conditions:

```
--> group by id 
--> calculate max of num
--> if the value of num > 1 per id, then assign the id as label 'A' else 'B'
```

I am able to find out the max value but unable to figure out how to assign the value to each row with common id.

The expected output is:

```
id          num  label
EBI-1002144 1    B
EBI-1002144 1    B
EBI-1002142 1    A
EBI-1002142 2    A
EBI-1002635 1    A
EBI-1002635 1    A
EBI-1002635 2    A
EBI-1002635 2    A
EBI-1003351 1    A
EBI-1003351 1    A
EBI-1003351 2    A
EBI-1003351 2    A
EBI-1003469 1    A
EBI-1003469 1    A
EBI-1003469 2    A
EBI-1003469 2    A
EBI-1003574 1    A
EBI-1003574 1    A
EBI-1003574 2    A
EBI-1003574 2    A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(num) over (partition by id) > 1 then 'A' else 'B' end) as label
from t;
```

If you actually want to update the table, aggregate and `join`:

```
update t
    set label = (case when max_num > 1 then 'A' else 'B' end)
    from (select id, max(num) as max_num
          from t 
          group by id
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.

If you want an `update` statement:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id,
        case 
            when max(num) over(partition by id) > 1 
            then 'A' 
            else 'B' 
        end label
    from mytable t
)
update mytable 
set label = cte.label
from cte 
where cte.id = mytable.id
```

If you want a `select`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when max(num) over(partition by id) > 1 
        then 'A' 
        else 'B' 
    end label
from mytable t
```